# Bing / Microsoft Maps Mode Selector opens on hover; how can I make this open on click instead?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

This mode selector menu constantly pops open on accidental mouseenter. Is there a way to change it to a click instead? I've not been able to find the code to control it, and was hoping someone's familiar with it instead of having to get deep in the Maps code.

```
<div class="NavBar_modeSelectorControlContainer">
  <span class="NavBar_separator"></span>
  <span class="NavBar_button NavBar_typeButton">
    <a class="NavBar_typeButtonLabel NavBar_MapType_be" href="#">Bird's eye</a>
    <span class="separator"></span>
    <a class="NavBar_dropIconContainer" href="#"><span class="NavBar_dropIcon"></span></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

[image: Bing Maps screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can't change the behavior of this specific element.
Therefore, you have two possibilities:

**1. Remove the dashboard and use your own implementation**

If you want to hide the dashboard, you can use the dedicated property on the MapOption class, see the `showDashboard` property and here is the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx

Or you can just hide the part regarding the map selector with the property called `showMapTypeSelector` on the same class.

**2. Change the behavior of the actual dashboard**

Be careful with this second technical hack as changes in the control might break your code. I would recommend the first method in fact.